# How to improve and run a custom validation method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, paperclip

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and Paperclip 2.3. Since the Paperclip gem offers only two validation methods (`validates_attachment_presence` and `validates_attachment_content_type`) I am trying to implement my custom validation methods.

In my model file I have *just* the following validation method

```
def validates_avatar(attribute_name, file)
  if file.nil? # file value is nil if no file is uploaded
    self.errors.add( "#{attribute_name}", "You must select a file" )
  else
    self.errors.add( "#{attribute_name}", "Avatar is an invalid image format") unless MIME_TYPES.include?(file.content_type)
    self.errors.add( "#{attribute_name}", "Avatar is too big" if ( ( file.size > AVATAR_FILE_MAX_SIZE.to_i ) || ( file.size == nil ) )
  end

  return self.errors.empty?
end
```

that I call from my controllers in this way:

```
if @user.validates_avatar(:avatar, params[:user][:avatar])
  ...
end
```

*I would like to make the above validation to run\to trigger the same way of all others Ruby on Rails validation methods* (eg: as-like `validates :title, :presence => true` works).

**How can I do that and how can I improve the above code in order to handle avatar validations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is already included in `Paperclip` and it do just the same job. so why do you want to repet it?

```
class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file
  validates_attachment_presence :file
  validates_attachment_size :file, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
end
```

and never validate in Controller - it is Model job. Just

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.save
```

It won't save `@user` if `@user.avatar` won't pass validation

Answer (score 1):

You should really move validations to a model. Here is an example:

```
validate :avatar_should_be_valid

def :avatar_should_be_valid
errors.add(:base, "avatar is invalid!") if...
end
```